# How to understand definition of rational numbers as set of equivalence classes in Lebl's "Basic Analysis I"?

Tags: real-analysis

This question is about defining the set of rational numbers as a set of equivalence classes (as defined in the book ["Basic Analysis I" by Jiri Lebl](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/18-100a-real-analysis-fall-2020/mit18_100af20_basic_analysis.pdf), on page 16 Example 0.3.25).

**Here are relevant definitions**

**Definition:** Given a set $A$, a *binary relation* on $A$ is a subset $\mathscr{R}\subset A\times A$, which are those pairs where the relation is said to hold. Instead of $(a,b)\in \mathscr{R}$, we write $a\mathscr{R} b$.

**Definition:** Let $\mathscr{R}$ be a relation on a set $A$. Then $\mathscr{R}$ is said to be

(i) *reflexive* if $a\mathscr{R}a$ for all $a\in A$

(ii) *symmetric* if $a\mathscr{R}b$ implies $b\mathscr{R}a$

(iii) *transitive* if $a\mathscr{R}b$ and $b\mathscr{R}c$ implies $a\mathscr{R}c$

If $\mathscr{R}$ is reflexive, symmetric, and transitive, then it is said to be an *equivalence relation*.

**Definition:** If $\mathscr{R}$ is an equivalence relation on a set $A$, then every $a\in A$ is in exactly one equivalence class. In particular, $a\mathscr{R}b$ if and only if $[a]=[b]$.

**My question is about the following example**

> The set of rational numbers can be defined as equivalence classes of a
> pair of an integer and a natural number, that is elements of
> $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{N}$. The relation is defined by $(a,b)\sim
> > (c,d)$ whenever $ad=bc$. Usually the equivalence class $[(a,b)]$ is
> written $a/b$.

Let me try to understand this.

$\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{N}$ is a cartesian product and is set (of tuples $(a,b)$ where $a\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $b\in\mathbb{N}$).

$(\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{N})\times (\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{N})$ is the cartesian product of this set with itself and any subset is a binary relation.

Some of these subsets are equivalence relations (the ones that are reflexive, symmetric and transitive).

Consider a relation which we call $\sim$ defined by

$$(a,b)\sim (c,d) \iff ad=bc$$

We have

(i) $ab=ab$ so $(a,b)\sim (a,b)$. Thus, $\sim$ is reflexive.

(ii) $(a,b)\sim (c,d)\iff ad=bc\iff (c,d)\sim (a,b)$. Thus, $\sim$ is symmetric.

(iii) If $(a,b)\sim (c,d)$ and $(c,d)\sim (e,f)$ then since $ad=bc$ and $cf=de$ we have

$$acf=ade$$

$$acf=bce$$

$$af=be$$

and so $(a,b)\sim (e,f)$. Thus, $\sim$ is transitive.

Thus, $\sim$ is an equivalence relation.

Now consider some element $(a,b)\in \mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{N}$.

Every element $(c,d)\in [(a,b)]$ is such that $(a,b)\sim (c,d)$.

For such elements we have

$$ad=bc$$

$$\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d}$$

The set of rational numbers is then defined as the set of all such equivalence classes, one for each pair $(a,b)\in \mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{N}$.

Having written this out, it seems like the reasoning I presented above is correct.

Is it?

Comment: I don't feel competent to write a full answer, but that's basically it. The relation is given like this, because division is not yet really defined when you construct the rational numbers.

Comment: The same technique is used when we create integers from natural numbers. If $\mathbb{N} =\{1,2,3,\dots \} $ then we can define a relation $R$ on $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} $ via $(a, b) R(c, d) $ if $a+d=b+c$.